# Segmentation fault when strdupa void pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, void-pointers, strdup

I'm fairly new to pointers, and void pointers is still black art to me.
In the following code I get a segfault when tmp->item = strdup(item);
I'm not sure how to fix.

```
int springmap_add(SpringMap *sm, char *key, void *item) {
    SpringMap *tmp = sm;
.
.
.
while (tmp) {

        if (!tmp->next) {

            tmp->next = springmap_init();
            tmp->next->key = strdup(key);
            tmp->next->item = strdup(item); // Segfault here
            return 1;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return 0
}
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* key[ESTS] = {"alpha"};
    void* ptr[ESTS] = {(void*)0xdeadbeef};

    SpringMap* map = springmap_init();
       
    for(int i = 0; i < TESTS; i++) {
    int status = springmap_add(map, key[i], ptr[i]);
    }
    springmap_free(map);
    return 0;
```

I'm not up to speed on void pointers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where did you get the idea you might be allowed to just throw some randome addresses to the compiler and pass them to `strdup`? For all the addresses in `ptr` array there is no reason to believe there would be a valid string at those addresses. You get addresses by dynamically allocating memory o the heap or by taking the address of a variable. Any hardcoded numbers are very likely illegal pointers.

Comment: If this is for some key-value pair, you should just pass plain integers, not pointers.

Comment: You should run your program within a debugger instead, because C is full of segfaults and there are all kinds of reasons to get one even one the simplest functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function name already tells: `strdup` composes of **str**ing **dup**licate, and it only is able to duplicate null-terminated C-strings (well, admittedly *any* data as long as it contains a null byte somewhere, though it would get cut off too early unless this null byte was the very last byte within the data).

`void` pointers in C have the unfortunate nature of implicitly converting to *any* other pointer type, happening in your code as well. However these pointers do not point to null-terminated C-strings, actually, they aren't even valid at all (most of most likely, at least)! Thus trying to read from them yields undefined behaviour.

So at first make sure that your void pointers point to valid memory. To use `strdup` they should point to C-strings, otherwise [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) is the way to go, though you need to `malloc` storage space as target first. For both, you need the size of the object available, though. However you *cannot* get that back from the `void` pointer any more, thus you need yet another parameter.

You could write your own `objdup` function covering the duplication:

```
void* objdup(size_t size, void* object)
{
    void* copy = malloc(size);
    if(copy)
    {
        memcpy(copy, object, size);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Still your pointers need to be valid! Some possible example might look like:

```
int main()
{
    SomeDataType o1;
    AnotherDataType o2;
    AnotherDatatType* ptr = &o2; // create a valid pointer
                                 // (could be done by malloc'ing memory, too)

    void* c1 = objdup(sizeof(o1), &o1);
    //                            ^ take the address of a REAL object!
    if(c1)
    {
        void* c2 = objdup(sizeof(*o2), o2); // or via pointer to REAL object
        if(c2)
        {
            // ...

            free(c2);
        }
        free(c1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That solved my issue. Thank you very much. I made my own strdup as above,